# Is there a way to do Scala programming in visual studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, scala

I have VS 2012 ultimate RC and recently I got interested in Scala so I was wondering is there a way(plugin) to do simple Scala programming in VS? Googling reveals some promises of it being possible but those informations are over a year old. I know Scala runs on JVM, but the info I mentioned mentions .Net version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of march '12 it wasn't possible:

> Visual Studio supports step-debugging of Scala.NET programs
>   but not their editing. Until a VS extension for Scala arrives,
>   Scala.NET programs can be developed with an existing (JVM-based) IDE

[Source paper](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~magarcia/ScalaNET/2011Q2/PreviewScalaNET.pdf)

The project looks a bit abandoned.

**Update:** 8 September 2015

The Scala.NET project was discontinued (I believe due to low interest), Miguel Garcia who is the guy behind this backend switched to work on [GenB](http://magarciaepfl.github.io/scala/)

Comment: an abandoned OS project?  oh the shock :)  Im getting IntelliJ and will try to play with that.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl I would say abandoned *ide support project*. The .net compiler for scala is quite fine.